# Simplify square root term by taking variable inside root

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify expression $\frac{\sqrt{1+b+b^2}}{b}$ to$\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{b}}$.

How to achieve this?

Comment: How is your target expression computationally simpler than your source expression? It may look prettier to you eyes, but it not simpler by _Mathematica_'s concept of expression simplicity. If you are looking for a way to pretty print your expression in discourse, then you are really asking about working with `HoldForm` expressions and not about simplification.

Comment: Simply speaking, if you are performing calculations keep in mind that your simpfied version is more expensive.  It as one additional division than the starting expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 expr = Sqrt[1 + b + b^2]/b;
(expr /. 1/b*Sqrt[a_] -> Sqrt[a/b^2]) // Simplify

(*   Sqrt[1 + 1/b^2 + 1/b]   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

You can bruteforce it for this kind of fraction where the numerator has a square root.

```
 exp = Sqrt[1 + b^2 + b]/b
```

Write a function that takes the denominator squared inside the square root

```
f[frac_] := Module[{num, den},
  num = Numerator[frac][[1]];
  den = Denominator[frac];
  Sqrt[FullSimplify[(1/den^2)*num]]
  ]
```

Pass your expression to the function to check

```
 f[exp]

(*Sqrt[1 + 1/b^2 + 1/b]*)
```